# context menu items gets selected on mouse over in mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, contextmenu

I have an application with a context menu. I use the `OnMenuSelect` method but it gets invoked when mouse is over the menu item, not when I click on it. Is there a method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is by design. The [`OnMenuSelect` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd5h5a75.aspx) corresponds to the [`WM_MENUSELECT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646352.aspx), which is sent whenever the mouse is hovering over a menu item.

To handle a click event for a menu item, you need to process the [`WM_COMMAND` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591.aspx), which is

> **Sent when the user selects a command item from a menu**, when a control sends a notification message to its parent window, or when an accelerator keystroke is translated.

In MFC terms, this means overriding the [`OnCommand` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t3ddsb9.aspx):

> The framework calls this member function when the user selects an item from a menu, when a child control sends a notification message, or when an accelerator keystroke is translated.

Comment: I have tried overriding 'OnCommand' But i cannot add 'ON_COMMAND' like 'ON_WM_MENUSELECT' in the messagemap (shows an error - type name is not allowed)

Comment: @sherin: That would be `ON_WM_COMMAND`...not sure if what you have is a typo or not. As usual, post the applicable code in your question if getting the name correct doesn't solve the problem.